# How to launch another program and interact with its textbox when fully loaded (or in idle)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a lookup program (.exe) that I want to launch that contains a textbox. I want to launch this program from my main form and copy paste data from my main form into the lookup program (.exe).

I've already wrote some code to do this and it works fine but I'm using Thread.Sleep() to wait until the program loads. I was thinking of something like WaitForInputIdle() but I'm not sure how that works.

```cs
private IntPtr handle;
private void launchProgram()
        {
                // Copy the text in the datafield to Clipboard
                Clipboard.SetText(serialTextBox.Text, TextDataFormat.Text);
                bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serial Search.exe").Any();
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    if (!isRunning)
                    {                       
                        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Serial Search.exe";
                        process.Start();
                        // Give the process some time to startup - I want to remove this line and interact when fully loaded
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serial Search.exe");
                        if (pname.Length > 0)
                        {
                            handle = pname[0].MainWindowHandle;
                            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                        }
                        var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
                        var vPprocess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serial Search.exe");
                        while (GetActiveWindowTitle() == "Serial Search")
                        {
                            SendKeys.Send("^V");
                            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serial Search.exe");
                        handle = pname[0].MainWindowHandle;
                        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                        var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
                        var vPprocess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Serial Search.exe");
                        while (GetActiveWindowTitle() == "Serial Search")
                        {
                            SendKeys.Send("^A");
                            SendKeys.Send("^V");
                            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to remove the Thread.Sleep part and just have the form instantaneously interact with the .exe whenever it's loaded. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the code down to:

```
private IntPtr handle;
private void launchProgram()
{
    handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    string fullPathFileName = @"C:\Serial Search.exe";
    string friendlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPathFileName);
    Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName(friendlyFileName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (P != null)
    {
        handle = P.MainWindowHandle;
    }
    else
    {
        P = Process.Start(fullPathFileName);
        P.WaitForInputIdle();
        handle = P.MainWindowHandle;
    }

    if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        // Copy the text in the datafield to Clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(serialTextBox.Text, TextDataFormat.Text);
        handle = pname[0].MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        SendKeys.Send("^A");
        SendKeys.Send("^V");
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

Note that [Process.GetProcessesByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcessesByName_System_String_) expects the "friendly" version of the filename without the ".exe" on the end:

> The process name is a friendly name for the process, such as Outlook,
>   that does not include the .exe extension or the path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take the messy route and check for color at a specific pixel which will indicate the program is loaded. Or maybe look for some CPU usage drop or hard drive usage drop of the process that can be associated with the program done loading